# Unable Import Json-Processing Classes

Tags: java, json

I have a requirement to load JSON file and work on the data set. Below is my test code.

For JSON-P jar file I went to `JSR 353` and downloaded `javax.json-api-1.0-javadoc.jar`. I added this jar to the build path. But I still get the error;

> JsonReader unable to resolve to a type

One thing I noticed is after adding the jar, I can add `import javax.json.*` but not individual classes

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.json.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("File Name: " + args[0]);
        String fileName = args[0];

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        JsonReader jReader = Json.createReader( in ); in .close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `javax.json-api-1.0.jar` file to your classpath instead of `javax.json-api-1.0-javadoc.jar`. The file you've added contains Javadoc of the source code, this will not help you load th e class you want.

You can download the required file from following url. 

`http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/json/javax.json-api/1.0/`

P.S. - Try to use Maven instead. it'll be easy for you.